# Report Viewer com dataset de objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

OLá, estou querendo montar um relatório no ReportViewer mas queria usar um objeto como fonte de dados, vi alguns artigos na internet mas não consigo fazer com que o ReportViewer encontre o meu objeto para selecionar, ele encontrar outras classes do projeto mas as minhas classes não.

Alguém saberia me dizer como tem que estar essa classe para que ele encontre?

Obrigado.

Comment: O que você já tem de código até então? Pode colocar na sua pergunta, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não testei, mas fiz a mesma pergunta no MSDN e tive essa resposta: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/68fa0198-d7be-4873-a265-ccb49f24e569/report-viewer-com-dataset-de-objeto?forum=aspnetpt